# Show only weeks with data using ALLSELECTED function in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get a simple chart with columns for one value and a line for another value.

1. I'm using a calculated calendar to show the week/year item with an
   order.
2. A table with all the data and a calculated measure in DAX to show
   the acumulated for every week.

My problem is that the DAX measure is forcing all the weeks to show in the chart, even the ones without data (because they will get the acumulate from the ones before).

This is the measure:

```
P-Soll(sum) = CALCULATE(
    SUM(TEVON_parts_current_K[P-Soll]),
    ALLSELECTED(TEVON_parts_current_K),
    'Orden Semanas_Soll'[Index]<=MAX('Orden Semanas_Soll'[Index])
)
```

This is how it shows:

[image: Chart]

And these are the weeks with data:

[image: Weeks_with_data]

There are more, but you can get the idea. Is there any way to show only the weeks with real data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try If like

```
P-Soll(sum) = 

VAR CurrentWeekValue = ...
VAR Cumulative=
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(TEVON_parts_current_K[P-Soll])
            ,ALLSELECTED(TEVON_parts_current_K)
            ,'Orden Semanas_Soll'[Index]<=MAX('Orden Semanas_Soll'[Index])
        )
RETURN
    IF(CurrentWeekValue = 0,BLANK(),Cumulative)
```

Comment: Why the "currentweekvalue" parameter? I'm not filtering for the current week. Can you please explain what is it for?

Comment: Hi, you are filtering values on graph by week (04/22; 05/22....) on X-axis. So, you can check if you have a value for the current week and select the result you want to show.

Comment: The value in X axis is just all the weeks in every year from 2018 to the end of the current year. It is only for showing the weeks. I can't use the current week because there is a current value and a forecast value (which will go till the end of the year).

Comment: You want to `show only the weeks with real data`. So you need to put `Blank()` values for both measures for week where you do not have 'real data`.